# How to specify how much space between edges starting from a node with tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I'm experimenting with Petri Nets and I want to add some horizontal space between two arcs starting from the same transition.

My code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
% Styles
[node distance=1.3cm, on grid,>=stealth',bend angle=45,auto,
every place/.style={minimum size=6mm,thick,draw=blue,fill=white},
every transition/.style={thick,draw=black,fill=black,minimum height=1mm,minimum   width=6mm},
red place/.style={place,draw=red,fill=red!20},
every label/.style={red},
pre/.style={<-,shorten <=1pt,>=stealth',semithick},
post/.style={->,shorten >=1pt,>=stealth',semithick}]
% Drawing
\node [transition] (T0) [label=right:$T_0$] {};
\node [place] (P0) [below=of T0, label=right:$P_0$] {}
 edge [pre] (T0);
\node [transition] (T1) [below=of P0, label=right:$T_1$] {}
 edge [pre] (P0);
\node [place] (P1) [below=of T1, label=right:$P_1$] {}
 edge [pre] (T1);
\node [transition] (T2) [below=of P1, label=above right:$T_2$] {}
 edge [pre] (P1);
\node [place] (P2) [below left=of T2, label=left:$P_2$] {}
 edge [pre, bend right] (T2);
\node [place] (P4) [below right=of T2, label=above right:$P_4$] {}
 edge [pre, bend left] (T2);
\node [transition] (T3) [below=of P2, label=left:$T_3$] {}
 edge [pre] (P2);
\node [place] (P3) [below=of T3, label=left:$P_3$] {}
 edge [pre] (T3);
\node [transition] (T4) [below=of P4, label=left:$T_4$] {}
 edge [pre] (P4);
\node [transition] (T5) [right=of T4, label=right:$T_5$] {}
 edge [pre, bend right] (P4);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Produces this:

[image: arcs starting from transition without horizontal space]

But all I want to achieve is this:

[image: what I want to achieve (from a text book on PN)]

How to specify the horizontal space between starting arcs in order to achieve the result showing in the second picture?

Comment: Can you please complete your code snippet to a full compilable code? That makes it easier for us to help you ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `calc` library you can specify `($(T2)!0.5!(T2.west)$)` and `($(T2)!0.5!(T2.east)$)` (you can play with the 0.5):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{petri,arrows,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% Styles
[node distance=1.3cm, bend angle=45,auto,
every place/.style={minimum size=6mm,thick,draw=blue,fill=white},
every transition/.style={thick,draw=black,fill=black,minimum height=1mm,minimum   width=6mm},
red place/.style={place,draw=red,fill=red!20},
every label/.style={red},
pre/.style={<-,shorten <=1pt,>=stealth',semithick},
post/.style={->,shorten >=1pt,>=stealth',semithick}]
% Drawing
\node [transition] (T2) [label=above right:$T_2$] {};
\node [place] (P2) [below left=of T2, label=left:$P_2$] {}
 edge [pre, bend right] ($(T2)!0.5!(T2.west)$);
\node [place] (P4) [below right=of T2, label=above right:$P_4$] {}
 edge [pre, bend left] ($(T2)!0.5!(T2.east)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

By default a reference to a node `(T2)` is a reference to its center `(T2.center)`.
So, command

```
\node [place] (P2) [below left=of T2, label=left:$P_2$] {}
 edge [pre, bend right] (T2);
```

draws a arrow from `(P2.center)` to `(T2.center)` which stops at `T2` border. You can introduce a distance making reference to an specific anchor for `T2` like `([xshift=-1mm]T2.south)`

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{petri, positioning, arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% Styles
[node distance=1.3cm, on grid,>=stealth',bend angle=45,auto,
every place/.style={minimum size=6mm,thick,draw=blue,fill=white},
every transition/.style={thick,draw=black,fill=black,minimum height=1mm,minimum   width=6mm},
red place/.style={place,draw=red,fill=red!20},
every label/.style={red},
pre/.style={<-,shorten <=1pt,>=stealth',semithick},
post/.style={->,shorten >=1pt,>=stealth',semithick}]
% Drawing
\node [transition] (T0) [label=right:$T_0$] {};
\node [place] (P0) [below=of T0, label=right:$P_0$] {}
 edge [pre] (T0);
\node [transition] (T1) [below=of P0, label=right:$T_1$] {}
 edge [pre] (P0);
\node [place] (P1) [below=of T1, label=right:$P_1$] {}
 edge [pre] (T1);
\node [transition] (T2) [below=of P1, label=above right:$T_2$] {}
 edge [pre] (P1);
\node [place] (P2) [below left=of T2, label=left:$P_2$] {}
 edge [pre, bend right] ([xshift=-1mm]T2.south);
\node [place] (P4) [below right=of T2, label=above right:$P_4$] {}
 edge [pre, bend left] ([xshift=1mm]T2.south);
\node [transition] (T3) [below=of P2, label=left:$T_3$] {}
 edge [pre] (P2);
\node [place] (P3) [below=of T3, label=left:$P_3$] {}
 edge [pre] (T3);
\node [transition] (T4) [below=of P4, label=left:$T_4$] {}
 edge [pre] (P4);
\node [transition] (T5) [right=of T4, label=right:$T_5$] {}
 edge [pre, bend right] (P4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The quickest fixes are

```
\node [place] (P2) [below left=of T2, label=left:$P_2$] {} 
     edge [pre, bend right] ([xshift=-1mm]T2.south);
\node [place] (P4) [below right=of T2, label=above right:$P_4$] {} 
     edge [pre,bend left] ([xshift=1mm]T2.south);
```

that modify the target point or you can give angle input to the `bend left/right` keys for example with 40 to both you have

[image]